# Connection string without localhost .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, connection-string

This question might be a little easy and a bit stupid. But here i go. im working with more people on making a .net core project. And they have to change the connection string every time because its not dynamic. Here is an example of a connection string.

```
@"Server=(localdb)\teste;Database=teste;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

How can i write it soo instead of giving the name of my localhost on the server, i make it search for it? for example:

```
@"Server=.\test;Database=dbtest;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

Comment: So you don´t know the database-name nor where it is located? You just want to search for a database on a given network?

Comment: Yep basicly! just wanted to search for a database on the network

Answer (score 0):

Im a bit dumb. It seems its like i posted, i was having an error on .netcore reference that is why it didnt made the connection with sql.

```
@"Server=.\test;Database=dbtest;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```